# SQL GROUP_CONCAT WITH EDIT TEXT

Tags: sql, rdbms, group-concat

can sql make this?

```
Before                          After
+++++++++++++++++        +++++++++++++++++++++
+ ID |   ID2    +        + ID |    ID2       +
+++++++++++++++++        +++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  |    A     +        + 1  |  A-1,B-2,C-1 +
+ 1  |    B     +        + 2  |  A-1,B-2     +
+ 2  |    A     +        + 3  |  C-1         +
+ 3  |    C     +        +++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  |    B     +
+ 2  |    B     +
+ 1  |          +
+ 2  |    B     +
+ 2  |    C     +
+++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm guessing that you are referring to MySQL since you referenced `group_concat` but please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify what database you are using but you referenced the MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function so this answer assumes you are using MySQL.

It appears that you want to do 2 things:

1. Generate a count of each `ID`/`ID2` combination and concatenate those values together.
2. Group those pairs of `ID2` and count into a single string based on the `ID`

The first step I would take would be to get the count for each `id`/`id2` combo:

```
select id,
  id2,
  count(*) Total
from yourtable
group by id, id2
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faa2ff/8). Once you have this value, then you can use both the `group_concat` function and the [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to create the final result:

```
select
  id,
  group_concat(concat(ID2, '-', Total) ORDER BY ID2 SEPARATOR ',') ID2
from
(
  select id,
    id2,
    count(*) Total
  from yourtable
  group by id, id2
) d
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faa2ff/7)

Comment: Thank for reply.Yes, I am using MySQL.I have try the coding but the empty data will display out '-<total>'. How to make it?If I wan ignore the empty data.